# grep not working in a for loop over a list

Tags: shell-script, grep, cat, tail

I have some log files. And I have a list of user ids. My log files are in a particular format

```
log-yyyy-mm-dd
e.g. log-2014-09-30
```

I am trying to search each userId in the log file. This is what I am doing -

```
for userid in 234, 283, 893, 982, 323; do cat log-2014-09-30 | grep -a "user deleted "$userid  | tail -1; done
```

Ideally it should search each user id in the file and print the last match. I will then search in `log-2014-09-29` for the remaining user ids and so on.

**But it is only printing the match for the last user id.**

```
INFO - 2014-09-30 22:49:00 - user deleted 323
```

What am I doing wrong? please help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the commas in the userid list. The way to pass a list to a for loop is to give it space separated values, not comma separated:

```
for userid in 234, 283, 893, 982, 323; do echo "$userid";done
```

prints

```
234,
283,
893,
982,
323
```

But

```
for userid in 234 283 893 982 323; do echo "$userid";done
```

prints

```
234
283
893
982
323
```

So, you should do

```
for userid in 234 283 893 982 323; do 
    grep -a "user deleted $userid" log-2014-09-30  | tail -n 1
done
```

Comment: Oh yes. My mistake! It works perfect now. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, we posted essentially the same answer within seconds of each other so I thought I'd just combine them into yours and delete mine :). Welcome to the site!